# Using a 2-3 tree to maintain lists

Tags: algorithm, list, tree

Suppose we try to maintain a list structure using 2-3 trees, and want to have efficient operations for creating a list, concatenating, splitting, and getting the value at an index.  My first attempt at trying to do this is to think of the list elements as leaves in the 2-3 tree and every internal node stores the number of leaves to the left.  That way if you want to search for an index, then if the index you search for is less than the value at any internal node it will look to the left and otherwise look to the right.  If it fails to find a leaf then the index is out of bounds.

However, I'm not sure how I could maintain this invariant in an efficient way when concatenating lists.  I could tack the tree representation of L2 onto the right-most available position in the tree for L1, and then try to update the counts, and then try to implement some insertion algorithm like that for 2-3 trees ... but at least my gut is telling me that I won't be able to make this efficient (i.e. O(log(n)) ).

Should I just keep trying to make this work, or was my initial decision to store the counts at the nodes where I ought to think about re-designing the tree?

Comment: If you don't need good worst-case time complexity, a splay tree is much easier. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm going to answer wrt. a Red-Black tree instead of a 2-3 tree since it is easier to reason about. This answer needs slight adaptation to work with a 2-3 tree)

Instead of having every vertex store the number of elements to its left, let every vertex store the number of elements in the subtree that it is the root of. When navigating downwards in the tree from the root keep a cumulative sum  **s** of elements that you have on your left hand side. Whenever you move to the right child of a vertex **v**, add the number of elements in **v**'s left child's subtree to **s**.

This invariant needs no updating when you are concatenating or splitting two lists.

To concatenate two lists **A** and **B** (that is, **B** is appended to **A**), simply make a new vertex **v**, and make **A** and **B** its left and right children respectively. Update the number of elements in the subtree rooted in **v** to be the sum of the number of elements in **A** and **B**.

Two split a list into two, simply remove the edge going to the root of the list you want to cut off.

(UPDATE)

Depending on the size of the lists, however, the tree might become unbalanced. After a certain number of "unbalanced" concatenations or splits, you will have to re-balance the tree. I must admit, I'm not entirely sure what the time complexity of this is. I'm pretty sure you can't get amortized constant time, but you might be able to get amortized O(log n) time.

Comment: The essence of this answer is correct -- a subtree size in each internal node does the job (whether you use a 2-3 tree or a red-black tree).  Since the subtree size of a node can be calculated in constant time from its children, maintaining these counts only needs to add O(log N)  cost to any insert/delete/concat/split operation, since at most O(log N) otherwise-untouched nodes will need updated counts.  Since most of your operations will take O(log N) time, that won't change any complexities.